# Integration involving functional equations

Tags: integration, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $g$ be a function that satisfies $f(x) + g(x) = x^2$. Then the value of the integral $\int \limits _0 ^1 f(x) g(x) \textrm d x$ is:

a. $\textrm e - \dfrac {\textrm e ^2} 2 - \dfrac 5 2$
b. $\textrm e + \dfrac {\textrm e ^2} 2 - \dfrac 3 2$
c. $\textrm e - \dfrac {\textrm e ^2} 2 - \dfrac 3 2$
d. $\textrm e + \dfrac {\textrm e ^2} 2 + \dfrac 5 2$

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: I believe that the condition $f(0)=1$ is already included in $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ because $f(x)=f(x)$ when $y=0$. The additional condition should be $f(1)=e$ else any function $f(x)=a^x,a>0$ is a solution and you can not find a value of the integral that does not depend on $a$.

Comment: @stity: You may be right that $f(1) = e$ was intended, but $f(0)= 1$ is not quite "already included": it rules out the solution $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are right

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous, $f(x) = \exp(cx)$ for some constant $c$.  Then
$g(x) = x^2 - \exp(cx)$, and $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\; dx$ is a rather complicated function of $c$:

$$
{\frac {-{{\rm e}^{2\,c}}{c}^{2}+ \left( 2\,{c}^{2}-4\,c+4
 \right) {{\rm e}^{c}}+{c}^{2}-4}{2 {c}^{3}}}
$$

It turns out that this can be anything in the interval $(-\infty, 0)$.  So (a) and (c) are possible answers, but (b) and (d) are not.

On the other hand, there are also solutions where $f$ is non-measurable.  In that case, the answer is "undefined".

Comment: that is why I think there is an error with the condition $f(0)=1$. The condition should be $f(1)=e$ so $c=1$ and the answer is c)